# How to fill dropdown top with specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to fill dropdown with a specific value in JavaScript I want top value be **July**

at this time first value shows **January** I want **July** at top and all
 values after **July**

```
<select id="monthToSelect"></select>

var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var option = '';

for (i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  option += '<option value="' + months[i] + '">' + months[i] + '</option>';
}

$('#monthToSelect').append(option);
```

Comment: You want April at top when you click April (or whatever you select)? Then rest of list underneath?

Comment: To set the highlighted item of the dropdown you simply set it's `value` property.

Comment: You want April at the top of the options list? Or you want April to be the default selection?

Comment: i want April top of the list , first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need array.sort()

**DEMO**

```js
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

var sorted =months.sort();
var option = '';

for (i=0;i<months.length;i++){
   option += '<option value="'+ sorted [i] + '">' + sorted [i] + '</option>';
}

$('#monthToSelect').append(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=monthToSelect > </div>
```

**EDIT**

If you need only particular month as first value then,

```js
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
       
   var option = '';
         option += '<option value="'+ months [3] + '">' + months [3] + '</option>';
        for (i=0;i<months.length;i++){
           option += '<option value="'+ months [i] + '">' + months [i] + '</option>';
        }

        $('#monthToSelect').append(option);
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id=monthToSelect > </div>
```

Comment: when i want July of my first value then ??

Comment: in that case you need to  set the value by specifying index as above

Comment: i am new in javascript  please answer if possible

Comment: @Sami its there in the answer

Comment: @Sami if you want July first then you need to do this option += '<option value="'+ months [6] + '">' + months [6] + '</option>'; and then the for instance that Sajeetharan posted

Comment: @Sami if you want to show july then it will be  months [6]

Answer (score 0):

Untested...

```
$("#monthToSelect option").click(function() {
    var clickedOption = $(this);
    clickedOption.remove();
    clickedOption.insertBefore($("#monthToSelect").find('option:eq(1)'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little modification to the code of @Sajeetharan, to actually show first the July month and to remove the duplicate values of the combo box.

```js
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
       
   var option = '';
         option += '<option value="'+ months [6] + '">' + months [6] + '</option>';
        for (i=0;i<months.length;i++){
           if(option.indexOf(months[i])==-1)
               option += '<option value="'+ months [i] + '">' + months [i] + '</option>';
        }

        $('#monthToSelect').append(option);
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id=monthToSelect > </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this below code help will you to get expected output

```js
$(function(){

var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var option = '';
var startMonth = 6;  //choose which month you need first via month array index
var mts = months.slice(startMonth).concat(months.slice(0,startMonth));
for (var i=0;i<mts.length;i++){
   option += '<option value="'+ mts [i] + '">' + mts [i] + '</option>';
}
$('#monthToSelect').append(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="monthToSelect"></select>
```